# GraphApi - verify if a Facebook page allow commenting with images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I was wondering if there's a way to know if a given page is allowing users to comment posts using images as attachment.
Right now, on the Application i'm making, you can comment with an image only to pages that support it.  Otherwise, it would give an error.
I want to know if there's a way to do it and if not, is there an alternative to prevent the user from commenting a picture when image commenting is disabled on the page.

I looked everywhere (Graph api docs, sites, forums, etc...) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Pretty sure there is not a way to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the link to [docs for page endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/).

**There is no field which explicitly says about image comments are allowed of not** .so i guess you are out of luck as of now .

Comment: I'll have to remove the image feature to allow simple comments only.  Thank you for answering!